# How to prevent deletion of files in a mounted folder while trying to delete a mounted folder

Tags: permissions, mount, delete

When someone trying to delete a mounted folder from GUI the folder doesn't delete but all the content inside the mounted folder get delete. Let me know any way to block the deletion of inner files

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  My first thought is give 'someone' (via group) or 'everyone-else' read-only access to the files, and not access to sudo. (POSIX files simply are read/write/execute which are in three simple rights: owner, group & everyone-else; delete requires write-access).  If you don't want to give everyone read access; make a group of the ones with read-access and give read-only to that group.

Comment: Is the problem that other people (not you) delete files, or do you have this problem yourself (that you delete files by mistake the way you describe)? Please edit your original question to describe the problem with more details.

Comment: @sudodus I have the problem , when I am trying to deleting the mounted folder. The folder still there with an error message but the folders and files inside the mounted folder get deleted.Is there any way to prevent this issue ??

Comment: How do you try to delete the mounted folder? Please describe the command line or GUI tool that you use. It is better to edit your original question to add this information (than to scatter it in several comments).

Comment: @sudodus, I have updated the question as per your recommendation. I have tried to delete the folder from GUI. I got a error message that not able to delete the mounted folder but all the files in side the mounted folder get deleted. I need to prevent the deletion inside the mounted folder when someone accidentally try to delete the mounted folder.

Comment: My suggestion is that you learn using command line tools (in a terminal window). This way you will get full control of what you are doing. For example: You must expect that, if you remove a folder, the files inside it will also be removed. I think it is not really what you want. Maybe you want to *unmount* the folder (not remove it)?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you learn using command line tools (in a terminal window). This way you will get full control of what you are doing.

### Command lines to remove a folder (directory)

If you have an empty folder/directory, you can remove it with the following command line

```
rmdir /path/foldername
```

This command will not remove a folder/directory, that contains files or subdirectories.

If you want to remove a folder/directory and also the files and subdirectories in it, you can use the following command line

```
rm -ri /path/foldername
```

or if you are sure, without any question

```
rm -r /path/foldername
```

Elevate permissions (with `sudo`) only when necessary, because of the risk to remove 'too much'.

### Command lines to 'see' and unmount a mounted folder (directory)

If you have a mounted {partition/file system/folder}, that you do not want the system to access, for example because you want to unplug a USB drive, you should unmount or eject it. Unmounting means that buffers will be flushed (all unfinished write operations will be finished) and the system will not longer have access to the folders and files in the {partition/file system/folder}. Ejecting means unmounting and also turning off the power (for USB pendrives).

You can list the mounted {partitions/file systems/folders} with the command

```
df
```

or if you prefer 'human readable' units

```
df -h
```

You will find more details with the following command lines

```
sudo lsblk -f
sudo lsblk -m
```

A mounted {partition/file system/folder} has

- a device name `/dev/sdxn` where x is the drive letter and n is the partition number, for example `/dev/sdb1`
- a mountpoint, for external drives usually `/media/user/label` or `/media/user/uuid`, for example `/media/sudodus/usbdata` (if the label is 'usbdata').

You can unmount it with the command line

```
sudo umount /mountpoint
```

for example

```
sudo umount /media/sudodus/usbdata
```

After unmounting you can unplug the USB drive safely (or turn off its power supply).

If you run

```
df
```

you will notice, that the {partition/file system/folder} is no longer listed, and the folders and files are no longer available. But they are not deleted, they will be available after you mount the {partition/file system/folder} again.